# Pass Angular JS Data to Button OnClick Event

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, razor

Is it possible to pass angular `js` data available on a `cshtml` page to a button click event?

the angular `js` object is referenced as `item.property. {{item.property}}` works well between the html tags.

The function is:

```
function ShowFileDialog(ProjectID)
{
    alert(ProjectID);

}
```

The `cshtml` that I would like to do is something like this, but clearly is very wrong.

```
<button id="button-view" onclick="ShowFileDialog({{item.projectId}})"></button>
```

I already have a work around - so others are not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my POV these type of mixes shouldn't be done. The closest correct approach should be:

Setting your **view** with a value in the way angular was meant to be used:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myVariable" id="myVar" />
```

and if you want to you get or use this value get it from the **view** like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    var param1 = document.getElementById("myVal").value;
    samplefunction( param1 );   
</script>
```

**[Online Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4Xtx4/)**

> **Note:**
>   In this example I used an `input` but you could use a `data-`*`myVar`* attribute and get the value from there as well.

Comment: I am just now getting back to this and it looks helpful. I am completely new to angular-js, so had no idea how it worked or what it is supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller,

```
$scope.project= {"Id": 1, "name":"project1"};
$scope.ShowFileDialog = function(ProjectID)
    {
        alert(ProjectID);
    }
```

then in your html,

```
<button id="button-view" ng-click="ShowFileDialog(project.Id)">show dialog</button>
```

If you have a list of projects as such,

```
$scope.projects= [{"Id": 1, "name":"project1"},{"Id": 2, "name":"project2"}];
```

then in your html use ng-repeat as,

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="proj in projects>
        {{proj.name}} <button ng-click="ShowFileDialog(proj.Id)">show dialog</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[see more here](http://curran.github.io/screencasts/introToAngular/exampleViewer/#/17)